# Gatling Load test Error : 406 not acceptable on Response

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I am new to the gatling load test. And i want to load test my simple project.But I got the error on response(406 not acceptable) and  my gatling code is below

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class simu extends Simulation {


val httpConf = http
.baseURL("http://172.24.15.225:10050/sample")
.header(HttpHeaderNames.Accept, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
.acceptHeader("application/json, text/plain, */*")
.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
.acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")

val scn = scenario("Scenario Name")
.exec(
  http("request_1")
  .post("http://172.24.15.225:10050/sample")
    .header(HttpHeaderNames.Accept, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
    //.check(status.is(406))
   .body(StringBody("""{ "inputData": "Wonderful" }""")).asJSON
)

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(30)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

And the response for the above is

```
failed in Response
    Errors ------------------------------------------------------------
     status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209),       
    but actually found 406
```

someone please correct my code.
But the RestAPI(postman) returns response correctly.

Comment: Do you check what kind of response it is returning..try removing the accept headers for a moment ..

Comment: i used postman restapi. It returns the response correctly. And also removing header information raises the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found an answer. There is no error in the gatling load test. But the problem is my backend coding. I have changed my response from String type into the JSON format like below

```
object ServiceJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

implicit val RequestProtocol : RootJsonFormat[Text] = jsonFormat1(Text)//request json format

implicit val ResponseProtocol : RootJsonFormat[SampleText] = jsonFormat1(SampleText) // response json format

}
```

It works fine